# Put image on another making black parts transparent

Tags: image, matlab, transparent

What I want to do is to put one image on a second image, but only those parts that are not completely black. How could i do that in Matlab?

What I have now is this:

[image]

So what I basically want is the same thing without the black border around the white sheet of paper. This is my code:

```
resizedBg(startrow:startrow+size(rscrop,1)-1, startcol:startcol+size(rscrop,2)-1, :) = rscrop;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can act as if you have a mask.

Let be your first image A and the second one B. You want fill with B everywhere A is completely black. It translates directly into Matlab as:

```
C = zeros(size(B,1), size(B,2),3);
C(startRow:startRow+size(A,1)-1, startCol:startCol+size(A,2)-1,:) = A;
M = repmat(sum(C,3)==0,1,1,3);
C(M) = B(M);
```

I expand the mask M over the 3 dimensions to be usable directly as a mask.

Comment: Not exactly... I want to insert A in B. A is smaller than B and i know the start position. A is a distorted white rectangle, filled up with black to have a rectangular image. B is the gray-ish background.

Comment: @user3038350 Answer corrected, is it correct now? I assume you want an image with the same size as B. Is your background a RGB-like image or a real gray one (1 byte per pixel)?

Comment: I am getting an error on repmat (called with too many arguments). Both images are in RGB.

Comment: @user3038350 Sorry for that, I made a mistake when allocating `C`. Corrected, it should run properly now.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error ^^ what exactly does `sum(C,3)==0,1,1,3` do?

Comment: @user3038350 Works fine on my computer. First line allocates `C`; since B is RGB too, you can call just `C = zeros(size(B))`. Second line copies `A` at the right place in `C`. Third line create the mask where to put pixels of `B`: if a pixel is black, all RGB components are 0, so the sum of the 3 is zero. So it computes this mask, i.e. the sum over the 3rd dimension compared to 0, and then replicates it over the 3 RGB planes. Fourth line fills the masked pixels with those of `B`.

Comment: Thanks, i got it working now :) changed it to `M = repmat(sum(C,3)==0,1,1,3);` Thanks for the help!